# Set transparent window background in Titanium desktop app

Tags: transparency, desktop, titanium

I need to set the background of a window to be transparent programmatically, once the window is already created.

This creates a new window with a transparent background.

```
Titanium.UI.createWindow({url:location.href,transparentBackground:true}).open()
```

Background transparency can also be set in the tiapp.xml, but I need to set it *after* the window is loaded.

I also tried the following

```
var win = Titanium.UI.getCurrentWindow();
win.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
```

which does not have any effect...

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Did you try to set the background in window focus event?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could create 2 windows with the same components, one transparent and one not. Once you want the transparent background to show close the other window?

`or win.setBackgroundColor('transparent');`

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into a click event and it worked fine for me. All i did was change the url to 'app://index.html' for testing purposes.

```
$('.button').click(function(){      
  // test
  Titanium.UI.createWindow({url:'app://index.html',transparentBackground:true}).open();
});
```

Have you opened the web inspector to check for js errors?

Comment: There's no problem creating a transparent window. The problem is setting the window transparent once it's created. The window whose background I want to be transparent is the initial window that Titanium creates from my tiapp.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you want the initial window to be transparent, add this

```
<transparent-background>false</transparent-background>
```

to

```
<window />
```

on the tiapp.xml file.